# mSecurityInputMethodService is null in logcat

Tags: java, android, null, gps, location

I wrote a little **android** app that should display the current location (last known location) of the smartphone. Although I copied the example code, and tried several other solutions, It seems to have the same error every time. My app consists of a button. Pressing the button should **log** the longitude and latitude, but only logs `"mSecurityInputMethodService is null"`.

Here's the **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int response;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onbutclick();
        }
    });

}
public void onbutclick(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(loc != null){
            Log.d("Latitude",Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
            Log.d("Longitude",Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
        }

    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},response);
        Intent inte = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(inte);
    }
}
```

I also used `<uses-permission>` in the Manifest file. I would really appreciate an explanation what does `"mSecurityInputMethodService is null"` really means.

Comment: Are you testing on a Huawei Device?

Comment: @Klatschen Yes, I am.

Comment: Have the same problem, Huawei Honor 7, Android 6.0. As this is an INFO log message, no need to worry about. My guess is this is an Huawei internal log message. (Can here to confirm as it is rather annoying)

Comment: @VincentNikkelen Do you by any chance have trouble finding crash logs in logcat? Because I one, cannot see them, neither can I see the logs created by Log. in the application!

Comment: @Fe Ri No, I have no problems with the Logs.

Comment: @FeRi I had the exact same issue, took me ages to track down. Only fix I could find was to use the emulator for getting debug logs :(

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For my Huawei device the following helps:

Dial:

```
*#*#2846579#*#*
```

and a hidden menu is shown. Go to **"Background Setting" -> "Log setting"** and enable the log levels.

Answer (score 2):

Huawei Phones disable logcat, a small improvement on the above answer

Dial:

*#*#2846579#*#*

and a hidden menu is shown. Go to **"Background Setting"** -> **"Log setting"** and enable the log levels.

Specifically enable: **AP Log**, **Charge Log** and **Sleep Log**.

Source: https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-phones-disable-logcat-heres-how-to-restore-access/

Comment: There is only AP Log. I turned it on, but the error is still showing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while accessing keyboard and the keyboard was not showing. And turning on log didn't help. It turns out i was using google keyboard and i switched to huawei swype and it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
log.d(...);
```

Use

```
log.i(...);
```

As the other answers suggest, you need special permission to read debug messages.