# onItemClick loads empty activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 2 activities, When I enter something in the first activity and press "save button" it saves the text via SQLite Database. In the second activity, I have a list of saved items, and when I click one of them, the onItemClick method needs to trigger and open up a third activity where I can edit or delete the selected item.
Now, everything works fine to that point, when I click on an item. When I tap it, the third activity loads, but doesn't show anything, and after few seconds it closes and drops me back to the previous activity. Here's the code snippets:

Code snippet of second activity, where the list is:

```
  DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private ListView mListView;
@Override
protected  void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
    mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mDatabaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    populateListView();
}
private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG,"populateListView: Displaying data in ListView.");
    Cursor data=mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData=new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()){
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //string name=the item saved
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG,"onItemClick: You Clicked on "+ name);
            Cursor data=mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name);
            int itemID= -1;
            while (data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if (itemID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG,"onItemClick: The ID is: "+itemID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(MoneyTracking.this, EditDataActivity.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that list item.");
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Then the "third activity" which won't load up:

```
private Button btnSave2, btnDelete1;
private EditText editText00;
DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private String selectedName;
private int selectedID;

@Override
protected void  onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_data_layout);
    btnSave2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveTwo);
    btnDelete1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    editText00=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText00);
    mDatabaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Intent recievedIntent=getIntent();
    selectedID=recievedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1);
    selectedName=recievedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
    editText00.setText(selectedName);

    btnSave2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String item=editText00.getText().toString();
            if (!item.equals("")){
                mDatabaseHelper.updateName(item,selectedID,selectedName);
            }else{
                toastMessage("Morate uneti nesto da bi ste sacuvali!");
            }
        }
    });
    btnDelete1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
            editText00.setText("");
            toastMessage("Izbrisano!");
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Database Helper:

```
private  static final String TAG="DatabaseHelper";

private  static  final String TABLE_NAME="mt_lists";
private  static  final String COL1= "ID";
private  static  final String COL2= "listndprice";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable="CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            COL2+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public  boolean appData(String item)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "appData: Adding "+item+" to "+TABLE_NAME);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns all the data from database
 * @return
 */
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return  data;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
public Cursor getItemID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT"+ COL1 +" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL2+ " = '" + name + " ' ";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}

/**
 * Update database
 * @param newName
 * @param id
 * @param oldName
 */
public void updateName(String newName,int id,String oldName){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="UPDATE"+TABLE_NAME+"SET"+COL2+"='"+newName+"' WHERE"+COL1+"= '"+id+"'"+"AND"+COL2+"= '"+oldName+"'";
    Log.d(TAG,"updateName: query: "+query);
    Log.d(TAG,"updateName: Setting name to  "+newName);
    db.execSQL(query);
}
/**
 * Delete from database
 * @param id
 * @param name
 */
public void deleteName(int id,String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="DELETE FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE" + COL1 + "= '" + id + "'" + " AND " + COL2 + "= '" +name +"'";
    Log.d(TAG,"deleteName: query: "+query);
    Log.d(TAG,"deleteName: Deleting "+name+"from database.");
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

EDIT
LogCat:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFtud.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the LogCat? I want to see if there is an error message being posted when your third activity closes.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev There it is, I think:)

Comment: That's not what I was looking for - while that's indeed the logcat, I'd like to see a stack trace. It should look like several consecutive lines of red text... It's also possible that there is actually is no error. I'll keep trying to figure out what's going on in the meantime, but please verify if there is no error being produced when you open your third activity.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev Picture updated, is this what's you looking for?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev Can you please provide me an email adress? I have some questions for you.:)

Comment: you are welcome to message me on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev allright, I want to add some color to my dateString in .java, is this possible? And how can I do this?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found what your problem is. You need to put a space in between your SQL keywords and your column names/values. In your code here your query is being written as "SELECTID FROM...". But it needs to read "SELECT ID FROM...". Notice the space between SELECT and ID!:

```
    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT"+ COL1 +" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL2+ " = '" + name + " ' ";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}
```

Change the above to

```
public Cursor getItemID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT "+ COL1 +" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL2+ " = '" + name + " ' ";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}
```

Also make sure your other SQL methods don't have the same problem!

Comment: I changed it, and now that problem is cleared! But when I tap on the item now, it says the following error, wrote by me: "No ID associated with that list item." , that's written in my first block of code, in populateListView. I can't get it what's now. I checked the SQL. The stack trace says this: "I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null"

Comment: Did you verify that there is indeed an item in your SQLite database with the name you're selecting? And does it have an ID?

Comment: @drunken-sailor Also, could this have anything to do with the logcat message about mSecurityInputMethodService being null? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587844/msecurityinputmethodservice-is-null-in-logcat

Comment: I changed the LOG setting in my huawei, and now he can get the name of the element, but still can't open the third activity and showing the same error: No ID... I put the new logcat screenshot, check it out above. I'm really confused now...Btw, What you mean about verify there's an item in SQL db? How can I do this? The code I wrote looks good, I just can't get it what's the problem..

Comment: I don't know exactly what I did with the code, I just went through every line and changed some of them, and now the app works fine!!! Thank you so much @Shn_Android_Dev you helped a lot!